# Android send data from android to the server as bundle

Tags: android

I know how to send data from Android to the server. One example could be using the below snippet code. However, my concern is that it is time consuming to send all data one by one especially if you need to send a lot of data. Is there a better way to make a bundle (compact) the data that you intend to send and send them as a whole at once ?

```
ArrayList<String> stringData = new ArrayList<String>();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("Item1",Item1);
json.put("Item2",Item2);
json.put("Item3",Item3);
postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);
```

Comment: you can create JSON and send that json as you show.. else elaborate more...

Comment: Let's say you have 10K entry in your android database and you need send them to the server. Do you send them one by one using this method or is there a better way to send them as a whole at once ?

Comment: you can send whole file to the server instead of sending records one by one.. you want to send whole database file or kind of txt file...??

Comment: if you send your data as txt file or whole database, how does the server handle reading, parsing and recording the data into the server's database ?

Comment: there should some mechanism for that.. else there is no option.. if you have 10K records i'll prefer to send whole file to send...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want, but one solution is to use a `JSONArray` in addition to what you are currently doing.

You would continue to create the `JSONObjects` exactly as you are, but instead of sending right away, add it to a `JSONArray`. Then on whatever iteration you want (say after you have added 100 `JSONObjects`), send the JSONArray to the server.

Comment: Sounds good. What about the limit of jsonarray? Can I put 10K entry at once and send them to the server ?

Comment: The only limits on JSONArray is your available memory. I don't think storing 10k JSONObjects in memory seems like a good idea. You might want to look into writing all of it to a file and then sending it that way.

Comment: They are already stored in the database, but sending one by one consumes time

Comment: @CoKoder Any kind of network stuff should be done off the main thread anyways. Either constructing a reasonably sized JSONArray in memory or bundling it all together either in a txt file or some other method is your best bet. I'll leave that up to you to figure that out.